# Javascript animation does not work in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, animation, raphael

I am trying to add some JavaScript code to my WordPress page that makes a blue circle move across the screen whenever the page is loaded (via the Raphael JS documentation). I copied and pasted the JS code into the "Text" section of my WordPress page but when I saved and previewed the page, not only did the ball not appear but all of the  tags were deleted. Here is the source code I inserted:

```
<script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var p = Raphael(10, 10, 400,400);
                var c = p.circle(100, 100, 45);
                c.attr({
                    fill: 'blue', 
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                }).animate({
                    cx : 300
                }, 5000);
            }
    </script>
```

Is there some standard way to use JavaScript in WordPress? All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must check your .js file path correctly, 
- use phoenix editor extension in firefox to check your .js loaded or not
- make sure your .js file position in top position before `</head`